# How can I tell why I have permissions to read a file?

Tags: linux, permissions, security, acl

Here's what I just noticed on my CentOS SSH account:

*stat output*

```
$ stat /dev/kvm   
  File: `/dev/kvm'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 39768216    Links: 1     Device type: a,e8
Access: (0666/crw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-07-12 13:50:33.015216048 +0200
Modify: 2014-07-12 13:50:33.015216048 +0200
Change: 2014-07-12 13:50:33.015216048 +0200
```

*id info*

```
$ id
uid=502(jacek) gid=502(jacek) groups=502(jacek)
```

*strace output*

```
$ strace -e open cat /dev/kvm
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/dev/kvm", O_RDONLY)              = 3
cat: /dev/kvmopen("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
: Invalid argument
```

*ACL info*

```
$ getfacl /dev/kvm
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/kvm
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-
```

Why did `open` succeed here? What mechanisms other than ACL can be used to tell whether a user can open a file or not? What are the commands I can use to query them?

Comment: Why you think open succeeded?

Comment: @Braiam That's visible from the trace. The real question is, why are you surprised to have read permissions, when all the permission bits are `rw`? No matter what category you fall into (here: “others”), you have read and write access.

Comment: Whoops, looks like you're right. I just assumed that it shouldn't be world-readable and didn't even read the permissions. Silly me. Voting to close.

Comment: If you're wondering about the “Invalid argument” part, and why you would have permission to read a file but attempting to `read` it fails, that's a different (and interesting) question.

Answer (score 2):

What am I missing? `/dev/kvm` is world readable (and writable) as you can see from it's permissions:

```
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-
```

There is no reason why you shouldn't be able to read it. Are you referring to something else?